# Windows Media Center (Vista): add-on or software for cutting tv recordings?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, video, windows-media-center

I own a Windows Media Center (Vista) which I use for recording tv shows and movies. I'd like to archive some of the material I record. I need a good solution which allows me to cut the recordings in order to have smaller files.

Which program or Media Center add-ons are there? It would be nice if there also was some option for re-encoding the recordings. **Bonus** for Media Center integrated solutions.

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used a combination of [DVRMSToolbox](http://babgvant.com/Wiki/view.aspx/DVRMSToolbox) and good old [VirtuaDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) to convert and edit the recordings. DVRMSToolbos has the option to auto-decode anything you record, using a drop folder. You can  use VirtuaDub to edit the movie, and convert it to xvid. Both are free.

Comment: Yeah, that's sound a viable solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Videoredo](http://www.videoredo.com/en/index.htm) is good.

Windows Movie Maker either came with Vista, or was a free download from Microsoft (it's been so long I've forgotten).

Comment: I've used Movie Maker. It was functional, but not great, I was able to trim enough commercials to get a long TV show on a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind switching software, [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/) has all that functionality (including automatic advert detection). It's primarily a Linux solution, but there is apparently now a [working Windows version](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Windows_Port).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't want to switch. Maybe I'll try that out on another computer.